# Header not coming to service while Get Request is made from Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, authorization

I have an angular JS application, from where I am calling a GET API. The API is OAuth 2.0 enabled, so requires a Bearer Token in the header. So, I am calling the http method like this:

```
var config = {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Authorization': "Bearer XXXXXXX"
    }
  };

  $http.get("http://host:port/api_call", config)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    });
```

But when I am making this call, I am getting 401 Unauthorized exception. Initially I thought of this as a CORS issue, So I whitelisted the origin to make call to the services host, but still didn't work. So, I checked the logs and found that Authorization header is not coming to the API application, though angular is sending the same.
Note: Is this the best way to make a service call from Angular?
I am quite new to Angular JS and thus have almost no idea how to diagnose or troubleshoot this type of issues. Can someone please tell me the possible errors/how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: No issue in your code. Issue is something else.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the API gateway. It was not able to make Cross Origin Calls and thus the API call was terminated there, hence Authorization header was not coming.